# rfm_table_order function in package 'rfm'

Tags: r

I am getting error message running codes below. Appreciate if someone can help. I think the issue came from the date conversion. Thank you!!

```
> # data structure
> str(bmdata)
'data.frame':   1094964 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ customer_ID: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ sales_date : Factor w/ 366 levels "1/1/2017 0:00:00",..: 86 66 81 82 84 85 105 116 122 124 ...
 $ sales      : num  182 120 91 63 58 56 251 24 269 113 ...
> head(bmdata,5)

  customer_ID         sales_date sales
1           1  11/3/2016 0:00:00   182
2           1 11/11/2016 0:00:00   120
3           1 11/25/2016 0:00:00    91
4           1 11/26/2016 0:00:00    63
5           1 11/28/2016 0:00:00    58
> # convert date from factor to date format
> bmdata[,2] <- as.Date(as.character(bmdata[,2]), format = "%m/%d/%Y") 
> # rfm analysis 
> rfm_result <- rfm_table_order(bmdata, customer_ID, sales_date, sales)
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: can only subtract from "Date" objects.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have not given the date to subtract the last data of the transactions to have recency. Try this:

```
 # some fake data
 set.seed(12)
 customer_ID <- sample(1:500, 500, rep = TRUE)
 sales_date <- sample(seq(as.Date('2016/01/01'), as.Date('2017/12/01'), by="day"), 500)
 sales <- sample(20:400, 500, rep = TRUE)

 bmdata <- data.frame (customer_ID,sales_date,sales)
 head(bmdata)
       customer_ID sales_date sales
1          35 2016-08-15    43
2         409 2016-09-02    79
3         472 2016-11-20   327
4         135 2016-05-08   191
5          85 2016-12-25   217
6          17 2017-05-22   242

library(rfm)

rfm_result <- rfm_table_order(data = bmdata,
                              customer_id = customer_ID,
                              order_date = sales_date,
                              revenue = sales,
                              # here the date, for example, Sys.Date()
                              analysis_date = Sys.Date())
```

Comment: you are awesome! I got it. Now, I do not know how to export the results (a tibble over 500K row) to .csv. Can I please bother you again? Thank you!!

Comment: You can use write.csv(dataset, "filename.csv"), putting also the path in the filename, remember to use / or \\ in the path.

Comment: That was what I did but the file returned blank :( write.csv(rfm_result,"bmdataRFM_output.csv")

Comment: I think there is an issue between writing a `.csv` and a `tibble` object like the output. Imho this is not the argument of this question, but an argument of another one you could ask. Hoping my answer is correct to your question.

Comment: I am still unclear what is the correct argument to export the rfm_result which appear in tibble into .csv or .xls. Hope you can reply with the code. Thank you!!

Comment: Try this: `write.table(rfm_result$rfm , file = "your_path\\df.csv")`. This should complete this answer. I've also answered to the [formal question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386027/how-to-export-tibble-to-csv/51514699#51514699) a bit better.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you!