# How to export tibble to .csv

Tags: r

I did a rfm analysis using package "rfm". The results are in tibble and I can't seem to figure out how to export it to .csv. I tried argument below but it exported a blank file.

```
> dim(bmdata4RFM)
[1] 1182580       3
> str(bmdata4RFM)
'data.frame':   1182580 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ customer_ID: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sales_date : Factor w/ 366 levels "1/1/2018 0:00:00",..: 267 275 286 297 300 301 302 303 304 305 ...
 $ sales      : num  101541 110543 60932 75472 43588 ...
> head(bmdata4RFM,5)
  customer_ID        sales_date     sales
1           0 6/30/2017 0:00:00 101540.70
2           0  7/1/2017 0:00:00 110543.35
3           0  7/2/2017 0:00:00  60932.20
4           0  7/3/2017 0:00:00  75471.93
5           0  7/4/2017 0:00:00  43587.70
> library(rfm)
> # convert date from factor to date format
> bmdata4RFM[,2] <- as.Date(as.character(bmdata4RFM[,2]), format = "%m/%d/%Y") 
> rfm_result_v2
# A tibble: 535,868 x 9
   customer_id date_most_recent recency_days transaction_count    amount recency_score frequency_score monetary_score rfm_score
         <dbl> <date>                  <dbl>             <dbl>     <dbl>         <int>           <int>          <int>     <dbl>
 1           0 2018-06-30                 12               366 42462470.             5               5              5       555
 2           1 2018-06-30                 12                20     2264.             5               5              5       555
 3           2 2018-01-12                181                24     1689              3               5              5       355
 4           3 2018-05-04                 69                27     1984.             4               5              5       455
 5           6 2017-12-07                217                12      922.             2               5              5       255
 6           7 2018-01-15                178                19     1680.             3               5              5       355
 7           9 2018-01-05                188                19     2106              2               5              5       255
 8          20 2018-04-11                 92                 4      414.             4               5              5       455
 9          26 2018-02-10                152                 1       72              3               1              2       312
10          48 2017-12-20                204                 1       90              2               1              3       213
11          68 2017-09-30                285                 1       37              1               1              1       111
12          70 2017-12-17                207                 1       18              2               1              1       211
13         104 2017-08-11                335                 1       90              1               1              3       113
14         120 2017-07-27                350                 1       19              1               1              1       111
15         134 2018-01-13                180                 1      275              3               1              4       314
16         153 2018-06-24                 18                10     1677              5               5              5       555
17         155 2018-05-28                 45                 1      315              5               1              4       514
18         171 2018-06-11                 31                 6     3485.             5               5              5       555
19         172 2018-05-24                 49                 1       93              5               1              3       513
20         174 2018-06-06                 36                 3      347.             5               4              5       545
# ... with 535,858 more rows
> write.csv(rfm_result_v2,"bmdataRFMFunction_output071218v2.csv")
```

Comment: That's the right way to use `write.csv`, are you sure you're looking in the correct directory? When you rerun the `write.csv` command, does the zero-length file's timestamp get updated?

Comment: Also close the csv file before running `write.csv` again

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I was looking in the correct directory because the file was created. However, when I opened the file, it was blank. I also closed out the csv file prior to rerunning the argument again and was getting a blank file still.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the result of the `rfm_table_order` is not only a `tibble`: looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269865/rfm-table-order-function-in-package-rfm/51299256#comment89704185_51299256) already solved, and using its data, you can know this:

```
> class(rfm_result)
[1] "rfm_table_order" "tibble"          "data.frame"
```

So if for example choose this:

```
> rfm_result$rfm
# A tibble: 325 x 9
   customer_id date_most_recent recency_days transaction_count amount recency_score frequency_score monetary_score rfm_score
         <int> <date>                  <dbl>             <dbl>  <int>         <int>           <int>          <int>     <dbl>
 1           1 2017-08-06                353                 1    145             4               1              2       412
 2           2 2016-10-15                648                 1    268             2               1              3       213
 3           5 2016-12-14                588                 1    119             3               1              1       311
 4           7 2017-04-27                454                 1    290             3               1              3       313
 5           8 2016-12-07                595                 3    835             2               5              5       255
 6          10 2017-07-31                359                 1    192             4               1              2       412
 7          11 2017-08-16                343                 1    278             4               1              3       413
 8          12 2017-10-14                284                 2    294             5               4              3       543
 9          15 2016-07-12                743                 1    206             2               1              2       212
10          17 2017-05-22                429                 2    405             4               4              4       444
# ... with 315 more rows
```

You can export it with this command:

```
write.table(rfm_result$rfm , file = "your_path\\df.csv")
```

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much. Truly appreciate!!

Comment: Can you explain how do you know that "rfm" is the name of the tibble?

Comment: @al-ash try str(rfm_result) following the code above. You'll see the strucuture of the output, and understand how to know what to fetch.

Comment: what is `rfm` in `rfm_result$rfm` ? That is not clear

Comment: A tibble containing the results. look at the previous comment.

Answer (score 10):

OP asks for a CSV output.

Being very picky, `write.table(rfm_result$rfm , file = "your_path\\df.csv")` creates a TSV.

If you want a CSV add the `sep=","` parameter and also you'll likely want to not write out the row names so also use `row.names=FALSE`.

```
write.table(rfm_result$rfm , file = "your_path\\df.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE)
```